# $Gal(E/k) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$, implies $f$ irreducible over $k$

Tags: galois-theory

Let $k$ be a field, let $f(x) \in k[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $p$, where $p$ is prime, and let $E/k$ be a splitting field of $f$. Prove that if $Gal(E/k) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$, then $f$ is irreducible.

As a hint, I am asked to show that $f$ has no repeated roots,
and then apply this proposition:

**Proposition.** If $f$ has no repeated roots, then $f$ is irreducible if and only if $Gal(E/k)$ acts transitively on the roots of $f$; that is, given any two roots $\alpha, \beta$ of $f$, there exists $ \sigma \in Gal(E/k)$ with $\sigma(\alpha) = \beta$.

Knowing that $Gal(E/k) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$, I can say there are $p$ automorphisms $\sigma_0, \dots, \sigma_{p-1}$in $Gal(E/k)$, and that I can index them such that $\varphi(\sigma_i) = [i]_p$ is an isomorphism.

Starting from here, what can I do to prove $f$ has no repeated roots, and how can I show $Gal(E/k)$ acts transitively on the roots of $f$?

Any help will be appreciated.

This question can be found on Joseph J. Rotman's *Advanced  Modern Algebra*
Third Edition, Part 1.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ has repeated roots. Let $S$ be the set of roots $\mathbb{Z}_p$ acts on $S$ and this action is defined by $h:\mathbb{Z}_p\rightarrow Sym(S)$ which has $n!$ elements  where $n$ is the cardinal of $S$. $h(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ divides $n!$ implies that it is trivial since $n<p$. Contradiction.